# Gaelic Spelling and Pronunciation

Tags: irish

What is the Irish language equivalent of the name Aidan/Aiden? I know that the name is derived from the Irish language. 
Perhaps a more difficult question: What is... or would be the Scottish Gaelic spelling and pronunciation of the same name.

Wikipedia says Aodhán in Irish 
and Aodhàn in Scottish Gaelic (note the accents are different).

all over the Internet there seems to be confusion with the correct pronunciation of Aodhán in Irish... specifically whether there is a "D" like sound when said or there is no "D" and it is in fact pronounced much like Ian. 
fyi: I know the Irish spelling of Ian is not Aodhán

I could find now Scottish Gaelic info on...well almost everything. I'm curious where this Wikipedia editor got that info and whether it's correct.

Also,  a simple one... Cearbhaill is my surname though I use Carroll a lot. 
My family says KYEARLL... ll as in the -OL in Carol. Would you agree?

Comment: It probably depends on what form of Irish you speak. Different dialects have different ways of pronouncing things; there is not only one "correct pronunciation" for all of Ireland.

Comment: oh I don't speak Irish. I'm Canadian. My ancestry is Scottish on one side and Irish in on the other. My father emigrated to Canada so it's not going way back.

Comment: I'm a plastic paddy maybe?  haha

Comment: Oh, right. Just take my "you" as referring to people in general then. Anyway, if you're speaking in English, you're not required to pronounce the name the same as in Irish; plenty of people have names that have changed in pronunciation over time.

Comment: I'm aware that there are various dialects and some aren't even mutually intelligible... but there's Standard Irish. Maybe no-one speaks that as their native tongue, but I'm trying to get an answer in Standard Irish and the equivalent in Scottish Gaelic

Comment: I'm new to this app    I wanted to make one comment fyi :)

Comment: @sumelic   my legal name is Aodhán Dickson Cearbhaill

Comment: @sumelic but I use Aodhán Carroll day-to-day. I do write Aodhán as it is, however I pronounce it Aiden Aidan etc. knowing that's not correct in Irish.     I just want to know how to pronounce my name with confidence when I visit Ireland next year and I'm going through customs,  as it's all Gaelic Spelling on my passport

Comment: I pronounce my last name "Cearbhaill" like my family does. Same way the former  President of Ireland Cearbhall Ó Dálaigh did.

Comment: well tons of Irish and Scottish people whose first name is Aodhán like the English Aidan

Comment: some do not.  they say something close to Ian    I will stick with what my family calls me and what I say and very much like    thank you for your input @sumelic

Comment: For Irish, the sound system is [described and exemplified here](http://www.gaeilge.ie/about-foras-na-gaeilge/an-gum/focloir-poca-pronunciation-guide/?lang=en).

Comment: @jlawler Thank you. I'm sure the answer is in there somewhere, however it's too technical for me. Even is I knew IPA which I have been thinking of learning for years now...there is a too much linguistic jargon for me

Comment: a dipthong for example. I am familiar with the word of course,  but I have no idea what it means.

Comment: A diphthong is a vowel cluster, like the /ai/ in _line_ /lain/. It's counted as one vowel for the syllable, but there's movement of the tongue from one vowel position to another while it's being pronounced. Generally the movement is up and to the front of the mouth (from /a/ to /i/) or the back  (from /a/ to /u/, as in _lounge_ /laundʒ/). This is very basic stuff, and you can't deal with dialect variation satisfactorily (or even sensibly) without mastering it, I'm afraid. Try J.C. Catford's [_A Practical Introduction to Phonetics_](http://202.121.96.130/download/20150821141425133.pdf).

Comment: @jlawler Thank you for the link to that document. I will certainly read it. I have an interest in linguistics, in fact I almost studied it in University (as a major), however I decided on commerce at Rotman in Toronto and ended up in real estate development. Despite all that I am only more fascinated by languages!

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut  Thank you I now understand the pronunciation of the Aodhán and the fada indicating which  vowel is stressed, and it's pronunciation. I can now boil my question down to whether the d or dh is pronounced anywhere close to  d  as is in drive or whether it's silent.

Comment: and would Scottish Gaelic have a silent d as in drive or a spoken one

Comment: I now understand the AO*   that was a typo @Gaston Ümlaut

Comment: I'm just writing an answer. I'll add some more to clarify the issue of dh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'll assume that the way your first and last names are written reflect the official written standard, the Caighdeán Oifigiúil. This amounts to a single way of writing Gaeilge (Irish) even though it has numerous dialects with quite varied pronunciations.

In this system the 'dh' in Aodhán would normally represent a voiced velar fricative (being in a 'broad' context) but I've heard pronunciations that have it as [j] or even elide it altogether. Stress is on the vowel with fada (the accent mark) and that vowel should sound like the one in 'born'. The 'Ao' has a variety of pronunciations, from [i:] to [ei] (and others). You could try something like:

Aodhán: [iˈɣɔ:n], [ˈeiˈɣɔ:n] or [iˈjɔ:n], [eiˈjɔ:n]

As for your surname, it depends on how precise you want to be:

Cearbhaill: [ˈcʲaɾəwɑlʲ] or [ˈcʲaɾəvɑlʲ]

The bh can represent either [w] or [v]; note that a brief schwa-like vowel is typically inserted between consonants such as the rbh cluster. If the pronunciation with [w] is preferred in this name then it's not surprising that it would (at speed) surface as how you represent it, i.e. 'KYEARLL... ll as in the -OL in Carol' — nice to see your family has retained the 'slender' (i.e. palatalised) initial consonant!

It's likely the case that the majority of speakers of Irish nowadays are those who have learned Standard Irish as a second language. One result of this is that there are many who don't fully acquire aspects such as the velar fricatives and some of the broad/slender variants, as they are found in the unbroken Irish speech lineages. As a result it's not unusual to hear the voiced velar fricative produced as a [g] as this is probably the nearest English equivalent. So you might hear people pronounce your first name as [iˈgɔ:n] or [ˈeiˈgɔ:n].

Comment: ... at least I know that your surname can't possibly Ümlaut!

Comment: Thank you for that last answer. I consider my question answered. That answer was direct and to the point.

Comment: Thanks! I was going to ask if it was clear enough and dealt with all the issues you're interested in, so I'll take it that it is and does. I guess the choice if which pronunciation you prefer to use is up to you. If you know which part of Ireland your family comes from then you could look into the appropriate dialect, maybe even find a speaker of that variety and ask them.

Comment: My surname was Anglicised long ago as Carroll. We are an odd little offshoot the of THE Carroll Family, an Irish nobel family (former), and. Fkcenturies a royal family of a Kingsom withim .

Comment: For centuries a royal family of a smal

Comment: I have been typing every comment on my pho.. The auto correct is spewing gibberish out and sending unfinished messages. . . .  Waiting for keyboard access

Comment: A couple of observations. 1. Stress only shifts to long vowels in Munster dialects; it’s not a general rule. 2. Medial ''dh'' is usually elided, not pronounced as a velar fricative (ɣ).

Answer (score 2):

The most common pronunciation would be something along the lines of /e:ɔd̪ˠa:n̪ˠ/ amongst all the Irish speakers I've ever heard or spoken with "as Gaeilge", both Gaelgóirí and second language speakers. I don't know why the séimhiú (lenition) on the letter d is ignored in pronunciation, but I can't recall ever having heard it spoken. I tried to find an example recording but the online dictionaries failed me as they don't usually cover names. The best I found was this video from TG4 of Paisean Faisean which has a lad named Aodhán on it. His name is spoken several times after 1:28.

https://youtu.be/6vID2PFOcDY?t=1m28s

Answer (score 2):

The spelling Aodhán reflects the Classical Irish pronunciation of:

[e:ðˠɑ:nˠ]

This evolved into:

[i:ɑ:nˠ]

in northern dialects and

[e:gˠɑ:nˠ]

in southern dialects.

In Classical Irish the digraph "dh" conveyed [ð], however this sound was lost in everyday speech by the 14th century (although still taught to Bards in their seven year training so they could preserve the meter of older poems). In the vast majority of cases "dh" merged with "gh", that is [ð] was replaced with [ɣ].

There were some words however where this was not the case, such as Aodhán, Cródha and Díoghras.

Comment: Interesting stuff about the bards.  Could you just tell me: what do those little "ˠ"s mean in terms of pronunciation?  I am a little bit of a Gaeilgeoir and understand these ns and gs to be "broad".  But **ɣ** is the *voiced velar fricative* (do **dh**ochar...).  So what's a funny little version of it doing in your IPA rendering?  Generally speaking: where should I go to learn how to write my Irish IPA symbols properly? Go raibh maith a míl agat!